# recover sorting from original report with PX.Reports

Tags: acumatica

I use the function PX.Reports, but the sort in the rapport is not avaible.
How I can get the original sort ?

[image]

I use this code for the moment :

```
Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
parameters["ARInvoice.DocType"] = Base.Document.Current.DocType;
parameters["ARInvoice.RefNbr"] = Base.Document.Current.RefNbr;

PXReportSettings settings = new PXReportSettings("SO643000");
PX.Reports.Controls.Report report = ReportLoader.CheckIfNull(nameof(ReportLoader)).LoadReport("SO643000", null);
ReportLoader.InitReportParameters(report, parameters, settings, false);
PX.Reports.Data.ReportNode reportNode = ReportDataBinder.CheckIfNull(nameof(ReportDataBinder)).ProcessReportDataBinding(report);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must use

```
ReportLoader.InitDefaultReportParameters(report, parameters);
```

and not

```
ReportLoader.InitReportParameters(report, parameters, settings, false);
```